Show where participants had to act like spies or thieves
I saw this show in Portugal, over 15 years ago. It was in English, color, and had not hosts I could recognize. 
The idea of the show was to have the participants go through many challenges that resembled infiltration-like activities. The participants worked as teams that wanted to be the fastest or just to finish the set of challenges.
Some of the challenges included:

A 3D set of maze-like pipes. one of the team members had to guide the other through the maze (using a 3d map) and the other had to crawl in there just by listening to radio commands
A room whose walls were a grid-like pattern (between each line was a small hole). In a few of those holes, were some cameras. The participants could see the cameras' feed and had to cover them with some Chantilly-like foam.
My dad remembers some challenge happening on a boat as well, but he can't really describe what it was

I also remember that between challenges, we could see this CGI cutscene of a skyscraper, which was meant to indicate that the participants were actually running through this tower and trying to get somewhere by beating the challenges.
Any thoughts on what this could be?

Was it for kids or adults? Was it shot mostly in a studio or also outside (like The Mole)?

For adults, and always shot inside as far as I remember

When I read the title of this question I immediately thought of Spy a BBC reality show where members of the public are trained, and set challenges by former intelligence agents.  However the challenges in Spy tended to be set in the real world and involved a mixture of tasks that involved unsuspecting members of the public and actors - what you have described sounds more like a studio based game show in the vein of Crystal Maze.
